# How do you change generated to object coordinates without changing the xyz

Tags: coordinates

I was just wondering how you change generated to object coordinates without changing the xyz

I am getting a little bit closer to it by adding -0.5 to the generated coordinate, but I'm still missing something. What is it?

On the image, it needs to look like the top and the bottom is what I have tried.
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "without changing xyz"? Changing coordinates by definition change xyz.

Comment: The (top) image you are looking for has no Z component (Z=0). Perhaps multiply by (1,1,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it a plane?

You should get it right if that's just a plane.

try applying transformations!

if that's not a plane then fiddle with those numbers and you will get it!
(if it's not a plane then the z dimension matters and the origin would be at the center, so it will not show that color as your looking it on a surface.

[image]

Comment: I think i need a work a round to make it work but thanks for the answer:-)